# Serving RDF/XML and JSON-LD representation of Java model with Spring Data Rest?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, json-ld, rdf-xml

How can I serve an RDF/XML and JSON-LD representation of a Java model via Spring DATA REST Using @RepositoryRestResource?

I was reading about content negotiation but only found example with @Controller annotation and I need explanation when used @RepositoryRestResource

This is my code.

**My Entity classs**

```
package ec.edu.utpl.gestiondatos.tesis.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Efren
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "TDI_DOCENTE")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "TdiDocente.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TdiDocente t")})
public class TdiDocente implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -8846422129143878578L;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "DO_ID")
    private BigDecimal doId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 13)
    @Column(name = "DO_IDENTIFICACION")
    private String doIdentificacion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "DO_APELLIDO_PATERNO")
    private String doApellidoPaterno;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "DO_APELLIDO_MATERNO")
    private String doApellidoMaterno;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "DO_PRIMER_NOMBRE")
    private String doPrimerNombre;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "DO_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE")
    private String doSegundoNombre;
    @Column(name = "DO_FECHA_NACIMIENTO")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFechaNacimiento;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQU_ID_NSGA")
    private BigInteger doEquIdNsga;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQU_ID_SGA")
    private BigInteger doEquIdSga;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQU_ID_SICA")
    private BigInteger doEquIdSica;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQU_ID_EVA")
    private BigInteger doEquIdEva;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 2)
    @Column(name = "DO_GENERO")
    private String doGenero;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "DO_FECHA_CREACION")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFechaCreacion;
    @Column(name = "DO_FECHA_ACTUALIZACION")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFechaActualizacion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 1)
    @Column(name = "DO_ACTIVO")
    private String doActivo;
    @Size(max = 120)
    @Column(name = "DO_CORREO_PRI")
    private String doCorreoPri;
    @Size(max = 120)
    @Column(name = "DO_CORREO_SEC")
    private String doCorreoSec;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "DO_TELEFONO_DOM")
    private String doTelefonoDom;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "DO_CELULAR_PRI")
    private String doCelularPri;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "DO_CELULAR_SEC")
    private String doCelularSec;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 1)
    @Column(name = "DO_PROMETEO")
    private String doPrometeo;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQU_ID_CITTES")
    private BigInteger doEquIdCittes;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQU_ID_NSGA2")
    private BigInteger doEquIdNsga2;
    @Size(max = 15)
    @Column(name = "DO_IDENTIFICACION_RRHH")
    private String doIdentificacionRrhh;
    @Size(max = 1)
    @Column(name = "DO_VALIDADO_RRHH")
    private String doValidadoRrhh;
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "DO_EXTENSION")
    private String doExtension;
    @Column(name = "DO_TECNICO_DOCENTE")
    private Character doTecnicoDocente;
    @Column(name = "DO_FECHA_INGRESO")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFechaIngreso;
    @Column(name = "DO_FECHA_SALIDA")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFechaSalida;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "USUARIO_APEX_CREA")
    private String usuarioApexCrea;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "USUARIO_APEX_ACTUALIZA")
    private String usuarioApexActualiza;
    @Size(max = 80)
    @Column(name = "DO_CORREO_PERSONAL")
    private String doCorreoPersonal;
    @Size(max = 1)
    @Column(name = "DO_ES_ADMINISTRATIVO")
    private String doEsAdministrativo;
    @Column(name = "DO_ID_TIPO_SANGRE")
    private BigInteger doIdTipoSangre;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQU_ID_RR_HH")
    private BigInteger doEquIdRrHh;
    @Size(max = 25)
    @Column(name = "DO_IDENTIFICACION_NOMINA")
    private String doIdentificacionNomina;
    @Size(max = 1)
    @Column(name = "DO_REPETIDO_NSGA")
    private String doRepetidoNsga;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "DO_OBSERVACIONES_REPETIDO")
    private String doObservacionesRepetido;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQUI_ID_NOMINA")
    private BigInteger doEquiIdNomina;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQUI_ID_REGISTRO")
    private BigInteger doEquiIdRegistro;
    @Column(name = "DO_CANTON_NACIMIENTO")
    private BigInteger doCantonNacimiento;
    @Column(name = "DO_PROVINCIA_NACIMIENTO")
    private BigInteger doProvinciaNacimiento;
    @Column(name = "DO_TIPO_DISCAPACIDAD")
    private BigInteger doTipoDiscapacidad;
    @Column(name = "DO_PORCENTAJE_DISCAPACIDAD")
    private BigInteger doPorcentajeDiscapacidad;
    @Size(max = 25)
    @Column(name = "DO_NUMERO_CARNET_CONADIS")
    private String doNumeroCarnetConadis;
    @Size(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "DO_OBSERVACION")
    private String doObservacion;
    @Size(max = 15)
    @Column(name = "DO_IDENTIFICACION_NSGA")
    private String doIdentificacionNsga;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "DO_FOTO")
    private Serializable doFoto;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "DO_FOTO_MIMETYPE")
    private String doFotoMimetype;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "DO_FOTO_FILENAME")
    private String doFotoFilename;
    @Column(name = "DO_FOTO_LAST_UPDATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFotoLastUpdate;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQU_ID_NSGA3")
    private BigInteger doEquIdNsga3;
    @Column(name = "DO_FECHA_INICIO_ADENDA")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFechaInicioAdenda;
    @Column(name = "DO_FECHA_FIN_ADENDA")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFechaFinAdenda;
    @Column(name = "DO_FECHA_VALIDACION_RRHH")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFechaValidacionRrhh;

    public TdiDocente() {
    }

    public TdiDocente(BigDecimal doId) {
        this.doId = doId;
    }

    public TdiDocente(BigDecimal doId, String doIdentificacion, String doApellidoPaterno, String doPrimerNombre, String doGenero, Date doFechaCreacion, String doActivo, String doPrometeo) {
        this.doId = doId;
        this.doIdentificacion = doIdentificacion;
        this.doApellidoPaterno = doApellidoPaterno;
        this.doPrimerNombre = doPrimerNombre;
        this.doGenero = doGenero;
        this.doFechaCreacion = doFechaCreacion;
        this.doActivo = doActivo;
        this.doPrometeo = doPrometeo;
    }

    public BigDecimal getDoId() {
        return doId;
    }

    public void setDoId(BigDecimal doId) {
        this.doId = doId;
    }

    public String getDoIdentificacion() {
        return doIdentificacion;
    }

    public void setDoIdentificacion(String doIdentificacion) {
        this.doIdentificacion = doIdentificacion;
    }

    public String getDoApellidoPaterno() {
        return doApellidoPaterno;
    }

    public void setDoApellidoPaterno(String doApellidoPaterno) {
        this.doApellidoPaterno = doApellidoPaterno;
    }

    public String getDoApellidoMaterno() {
        return doApellidoMaterno;
    }

    public void setDoApellidoMaterno(String doApellidoMaterno) {
        this.doApellidoMaterno = doApellidoMaterno;
    }

    public String getDoPrimerNombre() {
        return doPrimerNombre;
    }

    public void setDoPrimerNombre(String doPrimerNombre) {
        this.doPrimerNombre = doPrimerNombre;
    }

    public String getDoSegundoNombre() {
        return doSegundoNombre;
    }

    public void setDoSegundoNombre(String doSegundoNombre) {
        this.doSegundoNombre = doSegundoNombre;
    }

    public Date getDoFechaNacimiento() {
        return doFechaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setDoFechaNacimiento(Date doFechaNacimiento) {
        this.doFechaNacimiento = doFechaNacimiento;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquIdNsga() {
        return doEquIdNsga;
    }

    public void setDoEquIdNsga(BigInteger doEquIdNsga) {
        this.doEquIdNsga = doEquIdNsga;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquIdSga() {
        return doEquIdSga;
    }

    public void setDoEquIdSga(BigInteger doEquIdSga) {
        this.doEquIdSga = doEquIdSga;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquIdSica() {
        return doEquIdSica;
    }

    public void setDoEquIdSica(BigInteger doEquIdSica) {
        this.doEquIdSica = doEquIdSica;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquIdEva() {
        return doEquIdEva;
    }

    public void setDoEquIdEva(BigInteger doEquIdEva) {
        this.doEquIdEva = doEquIdEva;
    }

    public String getDoGenero() {
        return doGenero;
    }

    public void setDoGenero(String doGenero) {
        this.doGenero = doGenero;
    }

    public Date getDoFechaCreacion() {
        return doFechaCreacion;
    }

    public void setDoFechaCreacion(Date doFechaCreacion) {
        this.doFechaCreacion = doFechaCreacion;
    }

    public Date getDoFechaActualizacion() {
        return doFechaActualizacion;
    }

    public void setDoFechaActualizacion(Date doFechaActualizacion) {
        this.doFechaActualizacion = doFechaActualizacion;
    }

    public String getDoActivo() {
        return doActivo;
    }

    public void setDoActivo(String doActivo) {
        this.doActivo = doActivo;
    }

    public String getDoCorreoPri() {
        return doCorreoPri;
    }

    public void setDoCorreoPri(String doCorreoPri) {
        this.doCorreoPri = doCorreoPri;
    }

    public String getDoCorreoSec() {
        return doCorreoSec;
    }

    public void setDoCorreoSec(String doCorreoSec) {
        this.doCorreoSec = doCorreoSec;
    }

    public String getDoTelefonoDom() {
        return doTelefonoDom;
    }

    public void setDoTelefonoDom(String doTelefonoDom) {
        this.doTelefonoDom = doTelefonoDom;
    }

    public String getDoCelularPri() {
        return doCelularPri;
    }

    public void setDoCelularPri(String doCelularPri) {
        this.doCelularPri = doCelularPri;
    }

    public String getDoCelularSec() {
        return doCelularSec;
    }

    public void setDoCelularSec(String doCelularSec) {
        this.doCelularSec = doCelularSec;
    }

    public String getDoPrometeo() {
        return doPrometeo;
    }

    public void setDoPrometeo(String doPrometeo) {
        this.doPrometeo = doPrometeo;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquIdCittes() {
        return doEquIdCittes;
    }

    public void setDoEquIdCittes(BigInteger doEquIdCittes) {
        this.doEquIdCittes = doEquIdCittes;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquIdNsga2() {
        return doEquIdNsga2;
    }

    public void setDoEquIdNsga2(BigInteger doEquIdNsga2) {
        this.doEquIdNsga2 = doEquIdNsga2;
    }

    public String getDoIdentificacionRrhh() {
        return doIdentificacionRrhh;
    }

    public void setDoIdentificacionRrhh(String doIdentificacionRrhh) {
        this.doIdentificacionRrhh = doIdentificacionRrhh;
    }

    public String getDoValidadoRrhh() {
        return doValidadoRrhh;
    }

    public void setDoValidadoRrhh(String doValidadoRrhh) {
        this.doValidadoRrhh = doValidadoRrhh;
    }

    public String getDoExtension() {
        return doExtension;
    }

    public void setDoExtension(String doExtension) {
        this.doExtension = doExtension;
    }

    public Character getDoTecnicoDocente() {
        return doTecnicoDocente;
    }

    public void setDoTecnicoDocente(Character doTecnicoDocente) {
        this.doTecnicoDocente = doTecnicoDocente;
    }

    public Date getDoFechaIngreso() {
        return doFechaIngreso;
    }

    public void setDoFechaIngreso(Date doFechaIngreso) {
        this.doFechaIngreso = doFechaIngreso;
    }

    public Date getDoFechaSalida() {
        return doFechaSalida;
    }

    public void setDoFechaSalida(Date doFechaSalida) {
        this.doFechaSalida = doFechaSalida;
    }

    public String getUsuarioApexCrea() {
        return usuarioApexCrea;
    }

    public void setUsuarioApexCrea(String usuarioApexCrea) {
        this.usuarioApexCrea = usuarioApexCrea;
    }

    public String getUsuarioApexActualiza() {
        return usuarioApexActualiza;
    }

    public void setUsuarioApexActualiza(String usuarioApexActualiza) {
        this.usuarioApexActualiza = usuarioApexActualiza;
    }

    public String getDoCorreoPersonal() {
        return doCorreoPersonal;
    }

    public void setDoCorreoPersonal(String doCorreoPersonal) {
        this.doCorreoPersonal = doCorreoPersonal;
    }

    public String getDoEsAdministrativo() {
        return doEsAdministrativo;
    }

    public void setDoEsAdministrativo(String doEsAdministrativo) {
        this.doEsAdministrativo = doEsAdministrativo;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoIdTipoSangre() {
        return doIdTipoSangre;
    }

    public void setDoIdTipoSangre(BigInteger doIdTipoSangre) {
        this.doIdTipoSangre = doIdTipoSangre;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquIdRrHh() {
        return doEquIdRrHh;
    }

    public void setDoEquIdRrHh(BigInteger doEquIdRrHh) {
        this.doEquIdRrHh = doEquIdRrHh;
    }

    public String getDoIdentificacionNomina() {
        return doIdentificacionNomina;
    }

    public void setDoIdentificacionNomina(String doIdentificacionNomina) {
        this.doIdentificacionNomina = doIdentificacionNomina;
    }

    public String getDoRepetidoNsga() {
        return doRepetidoNsga;
    }

    public void setDoRepetidoNsga(String doRepetidoNsga) {
        this.doRepetidoNsga = doRepetidoNsga;
    }

    public String getDoObservacionesRepetido() {
        return doObservacionesRepetido;
    }

    public void setDoObservacionesRepetido(String doObservacionesRepetido) {
        this.doObservacionesRepetido = doObservacionesRepetido;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquiIdNomina() {
        return doEquiIdNomina;
    }

    public void setDoEquiIdNomina(BigInteger doEquiIdNomina) {
        this.doEquiIdNomina = doEquiIdNomina;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquiIdRegistro() {
        return doEquiIdRegistro;
    }

    public void setDoEquiIdRegistro(BigInteger doEquiIdRegistro) {
        this.doEquiIdRegistro = doEquiIdRegistro;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoCantonNacimiento() {
        return doCantonNacimiento;
    }

    public void setDoCantonNacimiento(BigInteger doCantonNacimiento) {
        this.doCantonNacimiento = doCantonNacimiento;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoProvinciaNacimiento() {
        return doProvinciaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setDoProvinciaNacimiento(BigInteger doProvinciaNacimiento) {
        this.doProvinciaNacimiento = doProvinciaNacimiento;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoTipoDiscapacidad() {
        return doTipoDiscapacidad;
    }

    public void setDoTipoDiscapacidad(BigInteger doTipoDiscapacidad) {
        this.doTipoDiscapacidad = doTipoDiscapacidad;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoPorcentajeDiscapacidad() {
        return doPorcentajeDiscapacidad;
    }

    public void setDoPorcentajeDiscapacidad(BigInteger doPorcentajeDiscapacidad) {
        this.doPorcentajeDiscapacidad = doPorcentajeDiscapacidad;
    }

    public String getDoNumeroCarnetConadis() {
        return doNumeroCarnetConadis;
    }

    public void setDoNumeroCarnetConadis(String doNumeroCarnetConadis) {
        this.doNumeroCarnetConadis = doNumeroCarnetConadis;
    }

    public String getDoObservacion() {
        return doObservacion;
    }

    public void setDoObservacion(String doObservacion) {
        this.doObservacion = doObservacion;
    }

    public String getDoIdentificacionNsga() {
        return doIdentificacionNsga;
    }

    public void setDoIdentificacionNsga(String doIdentificacionNsga) {
        this.doIdentificacionNsga = doIdentificacionNsga;
    }

    public Serializable getDoFoto() {
        return doFoto;
    }

    public void setDoFoto(Serializable doFoto) {
        this.doFoto = doFoto;
    }

    public String getDoFotoMimetype() {
        return doFotoMimetype;
    }

    public void setDoFotoMimetype(String doFotoMimetype) {
        this.doFotoMimetype = doFotoMimetype;
    }

    public String getDoFotoFilename() {
        return doFotoFilename;
    }

    public void setDoFotoFilename(String doFotoFilename) {
        this.doFotoFilename = doFotoFilename;
    }

    public Date getDoFotoLastUpdate() {
        return doFotoLastUpdate;
    }

    public void setDoFotoLastUpdate(Date doFotoLastUpdate) {
        this.doFotoLastUpdate = doFotoLastUpdate;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquIdNsga3() {
        return doEquIdNsga3;
    }

    public void setDoEquIdNsga3(BigInteger doEquIdNsga3) {
        this.doEquIdNsga3 = doEquIdNsga3;
    }

    public Date getDoFechaInicioAdenda() {
        return doFechaInicioAdenda;
    }

    public void setDoFechaInicioAdenda(Date doFechaInicioAdenda) {
        this.doFechaInicioAdenda = doFechaInicioAdenda;
    }

    public Date getDoFechaFinAdenda() {
        return doFechaFinAdenda;
    }

    public void setDoFechaFinAdenda(Date doFechaFinAdenda) {
        this.doFechaFinAdenda = doFechaFinAdenda;
    }

    public Date getDoFechaValidacionRrhh() {
        return doFechaValidacionRrhh;
    }

    public void setDoFechaValidacionRrhh(Date doFechaValidacionRrhh) {
        this.doFechaValidacionRrhh = doFechaValidacionRrhh;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (doId != null ? doId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof TdiDocente)) {
            return false;
        }
        TdiDocente other = (TdiDocente) object;
        if ((this.doId == null && other.doId != null) || (this.doId != null && !this.doId.equals(other.doId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ec.edu.utpl.gestiondatos.tesis.entities.TdiDocente[ doId=" + doId + " ]";
    }

}
```

**And this is my Repository**

```
package ec.edu.utpl.gestiondatos.tesis.repositories;

import java.util.List;

import ec.edu.utpl.gestiondatos.tesis.entities.TdiDocente;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface TdiDocenteRepository extends CrudRepository<TdiDocente, Long> {

    List<TdiDocente> findBydoIdentificacion(@Param("doIdentificacion") String doIdentificacion);
}
```

Comment: (Note that JSON-LD is a RDF serialization.) Do you mean RDF/XML?

Comment: yes, I want to serialize like:  produces={"application/xml", "application/rdf+xml", "application/ld+json"} and in the URL of my web services only change the value of format param like : ?format=json or format=rdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Pinto](https://github.com/Complexible/pinto) to turn your persisted beans into RDF, which you can then use Sesame's RIO framework to write as any RDF serialization you want, including JSON-LD.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Pinto

Comment: and then how I can integrate it with Spring Data Rest Framework ?

Comment: In precisely the same way you'd use Jackson to serialize beans to JSON.